# Python Get Access to locals() Back In 2.7 to Prevent Duplicates

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, restore

So I am creating a list of primes using the "sieve" method and a Python comprehension.

```
no_primes = [j for i in range(2,sqrt_n) for j in range(i*2, n, i)]
```

Problem is the Sieve method generates tons of duplicates in the 'no_primes' list. It was [recommended](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) to use locals()['_[1]'] to gain access to the list as it is being built and then removing the dups as they occur:

```
no_primes = [j for i in range(2,sqrt_n) for j in range(i*2, n, i) if j not in locals()['_[1]']]
```

Problem is, this ability has been removed as of 2.7 and so does not work.

I understand that this method may be ["evil"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631777/what-does-locals-1-mean-in-python) (Dr. Evil with his pinky at his lips.) , however, I need to remove dups before they affect memory with a massive list. Yes, I can filter or use 'set' to remove dups, but by then the list will have taken over my computer's memory and/or 'filter' or 'set' will have a massive task ahead.

So how do I get this ability back? I promise not to take over the world with it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python possible duplicate?

Comment: OMG, that recommendation to use `locals()['_[1]']` is *horrible* advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [set-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-set_display) (which automatically prevents duplicates):

```
no_primes = {j for i in range(2,sqrt_n) for j in range(i*2, n, i)}
```

You could then sort it into a list if necessary:

```
no_primes = sorted(no_primes)
```

---

For a further optimization, you can use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of `range`:

```
no_primes = {j for i in xrange(2,sqrt_n) for j in xrange(i*2, n, i)}
```

Unlike the latter, which produces an unnecessary list, `xrange` returns an iterator.

Comment: Should use xrange over range since this is 2.x and not 3.x

Comment: Fantastic! Works. I did not know about set-comprehension. I do now, and will research it further. Thanks.

Comment: Just looked into the diffs in range() and xrange(). I never knew that range() created a list in memory and xrange() did not. Good info to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and readable approach would be:

```
def get_primes(n):
    multiples = []
    for i in xrange(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            for j in xrange(i*i, n+1, i):
                multiples.append(j)
    return multiples

m = get_primes(100)
print m
```

Comment: Prefer xrange over range since this is python 2.x