# Using double square brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a file using an older version of Python, I found the following piece of code:

```
PROP_UI_COMBO = 'Prop_UI_ComboBox'
PROP_UI_COMBO[[]] = [_[1], [x for x in range(-1, 10)] + [26, 28, 30]]
```

And I'm wondering what it means to set `PROP_UI_COMBO[[]]`. What do the double brackets mean?
Also, (I may be wrong) I believe that `_[1]` is just the temporary list of `[x for x in range(-1, 10)]`. So as my question presents, what is the `[[]]` for, and what is the equivalent in Python 3.4?

Comment: `_[1]` This isn't a correct Syntax in Python.

Comment: [It is a temporary name used in a list comprehension by Python 2.6 and earlier.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632177/3496038) @NoMorePuppies

Comment: Found a reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632177/3496038). @kojiro

Comment: I couldn't even get the code to run in 2.5 http://codepad.org/wXRfuLF3, or on 2.6 on http://www.trypython.org/. You're trying to assign to a string, that shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two lines are not executed by Python -- if they were, an exception would be raised.